# Почему приведение 10000 к byte не даёт максимального значения byte?

Tags: java

Почему при приведении `int c = 10000` к типу `byte`, значение переменной становится равно `16`, а не `128`, максимальному значению `byte`?

```
int c = 10000;
byte d = (byte) c;
System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вы не вполне правильно понимаете, как происходит приведение типов.

При приведении `int` к `byte` не происходит вычисление «наилучшего приближения». Происходит по-другому: «старшие» байты просто отбрасываются.

10000 = 0x2710 состоит из двух байт: 0x27 и 0x10. Старший байт отбрасывается, остаётся младший 0x10 = 16.

Comment: не совсем понимаю, не подскажете что почитать на данную тему, чтобы лучше разобраться со старшими, младшими байтами  и т.к. далее в этой теме. Это наверное вообще не к языку программирования относится а к каким- то азам самого программирования?

Comment: @MaksimKorkodinov: Даже не знаю, если честно. Может быть, какой-нибудь хороший учебник по чистому C? В C байтовое устройство всего приходится знать просто наизусть.

Comment: Понятно, этого конечно на java не изучишь, не низкоуровневый язык.)

Comment: @MaksimKorkodinov, почитай про двоичную систему счислений, сколько бит в байте, какие значения может принимать байт, сколько можно в 2 байта запихнуть и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в `byte` можно максимум запихать 255. У вас происходит переполнение разрядной сетки. Размер типа `byte` - `256`. Найти число, которое получится после приведения просто - достаточно взять модуль:

```
10000 % 256 = 16;
```

Comment: а зачем брать модуль?

Comment: @MaksimKorkodinov это я как пример, чтоб понять, что будет в итоге.

Comment: @MaksimKorkodinov потому что операция взятия остатка по модулю 256 возвращает младший байт